# Java Nashorn: Abstract Class in JS falling back on JS function?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm creating a class in JS, that then needs to be able to access functions from the original JS. It's a bit more tricky in my options though, because the function names are just "button_A_NUMBER" that can range from 0 to over 500. I'm new to using JavaScript past simple changes here and there on a webpage, so I'm not sure if I'm completely off here.

I was using this["button_" + interfaceID] () which was working great up until I changed it to be a class instead of a function.

JS File 1

```js
function DecodedPacketButton(index) {
    var classObject = new DecodedPacket(index, 8, this) {
        complete: function(player, args) {
            try {
                var interfaceID = args[0];
                var childID = args[1];
                var slot1 = args[2];
                var slot2 = args[3];
                classObject.callMember("button_" + interfaceID, player,
                        classObject.index(), interfaceID, childID, slot1, slot2);
            } catch (e) {
                Logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    };
    return classObject;
}

function DecodedPacket121() {
    return DecodedPacketButton(0);
}
```

JS File 2

```js
DecodedPacketButton.prototype.button_182
        = function(player, index, interfaceID, childID, slot1, slot2) { }
```

Java Class

```js
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

public abstract class DecodedPacket {
    private int index;
    private int size;
    private ScriptObjectMirror mirror;

    public DecodedPacket(int index, int size, ScriptObjectMirror mirror) {
        this.index = index;
        this.size = size;
        this.mirror = mirror;
    }

    public abstract void complete(Player p, Object... args);

    public void callMember(String functionName, Object... args) {
        mirror.callMember(functionName, args);
    }

    public void call(String functionName, Object... args) {
        mirror.call(functionName, args);
    }
}
```

I thought call or callMember would be what I'm looking for, but neither seem to do the trick.

Comment: So, you're trying to call functioned based on a number in their name? DON'T DO THAT. If you really need to access functions by an index, put them in a list, and index and call from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call function by name, the simplest way is to place them in an object literal.

```js
var funcs = {
  func1: function () { console.log('this is function 1') },
  func2: function () { console.log('this is function 2') }
};
                      
function callFunc(name) {
  if (funcs[name]) funcs[name]();
  else console.log('Function ' + name + ' not found.');
}
                      
callFunc('func1');
callFunc('func2');
callFunc('func3');
```

Comment: The problem with this is I have each button function in it's own js file to help keep things sorted and easier to manage as some of them can be on the larger side. I'm also not sure how I'd go about callFunc in place of classObject.callMember in my above code. Am I able to directly reference functions in the class I create in js?

Comment: As long as you can reference the javascript function you can call it,. if you want to call a member of an object by string it's the same thing..  obj[somestring].somemethod(param1, param2, etc)..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my original code working as-is by simply making DecodedPacketButton returned as new DecodedPacketButton instead. If someone can explain the need for new to me and the differences in using it or not, I'd appreciate it.